# Using a Model With a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm having trouble accessing the ID of a model I am adding to a `ComboBox`. At the moment I have a model, a `preset`, that contains an ID and Text. I create a list of `presets` through OleDB and then filter the list down before adding the contents to a `ComboBox`. Here is the code that does this;

```
        var ps = new PresetService();
        List<PresetModel> presetList = ps.HandleGetPresets();
        List<PresetModel> filteredList = presetList.Where(filteredPreset => filteredPreset.PresetReferenceFoxPro == 3).ToList();

        try
        {
            foreach (PresetModel preset in filteredList)
            {
                presetComboBox.Items.Add(preset.PresetText);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var hEs = new HandleExceptionService();
            hEs.HandleException(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
```

Here you can see that I am adding the `preset's` text to the `ComboBox`. The issue comes however when someone wants to add a Company using one of the `presets`. In this case I am actually not interested in the text, I just want to add the `preset's` ID to the database against a company instead.

Using `SelectedItem` is not allowing me to access the ID, it returns a null exception. This is what I've triedl

```
var selectedPreset = presetComboBox.SelectedItem as PresetModel;
var presetIDToAdd = selectedPreset.PresetID;
```

I assume that this does not work because I have simply added the `preset's` Text value to the `ComboBox` and not it's ID. How can I add  `preset` to a `ComboBox`, only display it's text but access it's ID when needed?

Comment: Add the preset then on combobox set DisplayMemberPath="PresetText". That should display the text only but at the same time it should give you the ID you need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are adding the `PresetText` to the `ComboBox`, not the `PresetModel` itself:

```
presetComboBox.Items.Add(preset.PresetText);
```

On top of that, you are then trying to cast the `SelectedItem` to a `PresetModel`, but it's actually the `PresetText`.

I would suggest using the following method.

Firstly, add the whole object to the `ComboBox`, like this:

```
presetComboBox.Items.Add(preset);
```

You can then define an `ItemTemplate` on your `ComboBox` to display the `PresetText`, **or**, to make things easier, just set the `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
<ComboBox ...
          DisplayMemberPath="PresetText"/>
```

This will allow you to cast the `SelectedItem` to a `PresetModel`, but also still displaying the `PresetText` property in the `ComboBox`.